# Oracle SQL 11gR2 => find out all dates where "impdp" was performed

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, import

Hello my team performed several database `Data Pump Import "impdp"` over the last two years.

The workflow was always to import all "application" schemas ( The schemas that are used from our application) `dailyBackup-2019-04-05.sql` dump from one of the daily backups.

Now I need to find out the exact dates whe the `"impdp"`restores where performed.

I tried the following:
[image]

I found the file `dpdump` on my server but it only contains this three lines:

[image]

I only have **one** "import.log" file that got always overridden every time a restore with `dpdump` was taken.

Are there maybe system tables tables where I can check every time when a `dpdump` was performed

Where else can I look for the log some "import log" files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time a Data Pump job like that is started, the database notes this in the database alert log. If you have the alert log, you can find the entries there.

Other than that, the database does not store a history of the Data Pump jobs, unless you specifically instruct Data Pump to keep the metadata by adding the `KEEP_MASTER=yes` parameter to your job.